# Dataset of Brazilian Portuguese audio classified by emotion

Tags: data-request, sentiment-analysis, brazil

I plan to create an algorithm for detecting voice sentiment in Brazilian Portuguese, but i wasn't able to find any datasets to train the model with. If anyone knows where I could find a dataset of voices classified by emotion in Brazilian Portuguese, I would greatly appreciate it.

Region: no region requirements as long as the data is in Brazilian Portuguese and preferably voiced by native speakers.

License: open data.

Format: preferably a csv file, but any format will do.